# How to point to the current directory while executing commands

Tags: command-line, bash

This question must have been asked before, but I faced an error message that I couldn't find much about...

I want to create a link for a directory (its content) `~/abc/def/ghi/` to another directory `~/tuv/wxy`. I am currently on the source directory so I do the command below:

```
$ ln -s ./ ~/tuv/wxy
```

but when I go to `~/tuv/` I see that `wxy` is pointing to `./` and obviously the link creation has failed.

So my question is how can I execute the command above without the need to type the full  (or generally this can be useful for a lot of cases).

Maybe what I need is to use pipes, something like `pwd | ln -s "$RESULT" ~/tuw/wxy` but I do not know the current syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `PWD` variable, or the `pwd` command with command substitution:

```
ln -s "$PWD" ~/tuv/wxy
ln -s "$(pwd)" ~/tuv/wxy
```